# Lightning Web Component not getting deployed

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, visualstudiocode

I have been trying to deploy a lightning web component and an apex class to a developer org, but I receive the error "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run" in VS Code.

Did I miss something when I set-up VS Code?

1. Salesforce CLI is up to date
2. All extensions are up to date
3. The orgs in question have been authorized successfully

**I was able to deploy the "datatableStudentController" apex class successfully** so I assume the connection with VS code and my org is fine, not sure why "datatableRecords.html", "datatableRecords.js" and "datatableRecords.js-meta.xml" won't get deployed. Screenshots of my codes are given below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using right click to lwc folder and deploy or use command line manually to see the deploy. I had seen similar error and was able to work with folder-right click> deploy

Comment: Can you check Problems tab to see if there any message there? Usually when it says  Deploy Errors without any message on Output tab, error message appears in Problems tab.

Comment: @YsrShk - It still didn't work.

Comment: what error did you receive, when you attempted with CLI approach

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive. In your LWC controller the variable is defined as `dataTable`, however in component if:true it shows datatable. Also in lightning-datatable data attribute should have curl braces like shown below instead of double quotes.

```
<template if:true={dataTable}>

<lightning-datatable data={dataTable} columns={columns}.....
```

In LWC controller

```
export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    .......
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out. I have corrected those but still I cannot deploy it. The same error message is coming up and there are no messages in the Problem tab at that time.

Comment: I added the columns part as well. Also do you have Salesforce Extension Pack (Expanded) installed in your visual studio code? It does have extra plugins for Javascript and LWC that might help you flag the problem.

Comment: Yes I have the extension packs installed but for some reason it is not getting deployed.